# Clear Redis Cache periodically using Lambda

Tags: node.js, redis, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

I am writing a Lambda function that connects to AWS ElastiCache Redis. This Lambda function will talk to a database to return a list of records and cache those records to ElastiCache Redis. Sometimes, new records will be added to the database, I want my Lambda to clear Redis cache once a day and recache all records again. Does anyone know how to configure ElastiCache Redis to clear its cache periodically?

Comment: Redis comes with a inbuilt [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire) which you can use while writing the key.  If you want, you can `flush` the db by a lambda function as well. AFAIK, there is no inbuilt function which can do that for you.

Comment: In Redis documentation for Node https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis, I found this:
**client.set('key', 'value!', 'EX', 10);**
but when I implemented it, I got an error of invalid param in SET. I ended up using EXPIRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to drop cache once a day, just set its expiration to the end of the day.

But you're saying "drop and recache". How will Redis do it? You need to configure your Lambda (or write another one) to do that for you. And you better compute new values before dropping old ones.

Comment: As far as I've researched, there is no such Redis's command that does "drop and recache" for me, so I add some conditional statements to do that function for me.  
**Pseudocode**  
if (cachedData) {  
   // Do something with it   
} else {   
  // Make request to service for the data, catch it, then set expire time  
}

Comment: Right,  it was a rhetorical question.